# Azure Windows Virtual Machine Activation

Tags: azure, windows-server-2022

I am currently using 3 Windows VMs on Azure. All of them are server 2022 datacenter edition. Now one of the VMs is showing activated while the other 2 are not. I am using these for lab practices. I don't need it but very curious as to what happened. I created all the 3 VMs in the same way on Azure portal.

Comment: Do you have any NSG rules that block outbound access? This may block access to the KMS server

Comment: Nope @SamCogan....I even tried port 1688 testing .........and it returned true........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, if you want to activate them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/automatic-vm-activation